# save user login session in Android webview

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an android app using webview function to my website and the member can log in first then will redirect to another page.

it works perfectly but the only problem after I closed the app and clear it from the recent item the next time I OPEN the app I have to log in again and again.

I want to save the member's credential user name and password to avoid login in every time I use the app.

I try to save the Cookie or AppCache but it doesn't work

here is my code

```
 webView = (WebView)  findViewById(R.id.web);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/index.php");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Try using sharedpreferences and save the details in local once user login and always check before loggin ...that are there any credentials then use them

Comment: I was trying to do this but it's not working I am not sure if u have an example of it I will appreciate it. @SumitSingh

Comment: Will give you in some time